# Starting activities and sharing data on Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-tabhost

I am new to Android programming and I have hit a problem that I cannot overcome. I have built up a TabHost application using the Android Studio examples. When the user presses a button I would like to call another activity that brings up a settings page (I created a basic activity 'MySettings' from gui).

Problem 1: When the activity closes, the MainActivity reruns onCreate and the selected tab goes back to the startup tab. Is there a way to just continue on the Tab that was last selected?

Calling code is:

```
public void buttonPressed(View view) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MySettings.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Problem 2: I cannot share data between the two activities:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

}
```

MySettings:

```
public class MySettings extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_inr);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("myvar",200);
    sharedpreferences.edit().apply();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
};
```

This code runs, but when the MySettings activity closes, 'myvar' is not updated in the calling activity MainActivity.

```
public void setImage(){
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int cvt=sharedpreferences.getInt("myvar",0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

You should save the selected tab index in your activity so that when it goes back, you can read the index and select it when onCreate called.

**Problem 2:**

@Luis Miguel Sierra is right about the SharedPreference thing.

But You may want 'startActivityForResult' to pass data back to the first activity.

> Starting another activity doesn't have to be one-way. You can also start another activity and receive a result back. To receive a result, call startActivityForResult() (instead of startActivity()).
>
> For example, your app can start a camera app and receive the captured photo as a result. Or, you might start the People app in order for the user to select a contact and you'll receive the contact details as a result.
>
> Of course, the activity that responds must be designed to return a result. When it does, it sends the result as another Intent object. Your activity receives it in the onActivityResult() callback.

Further information:
[Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution of 2nd Problem**

Within the help of **Intent** you can transfer data Form one Activity to another

like following

```
public void buttonPressed(View view) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MySettings.class);
intent.putExtra("key","value");
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

At the second Activity

```
String value=getIntent().getStrigExtras("key");
```

will return the value

**Solution of 1st Problem**

You should save the position of a tab which is selected and when you are return back to that activity assign this position to tabhost to reselected  your Tabs

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to set current selected tab onBackPress then just save the selected tab index and you can reset it using below code

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

If you want all of data that you receive on first actvity to second activity then you can use following code to send data through Intent

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", iddata);
    intent.putExtra("title", titledata); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

Code To Receive Data that sent through Intent in SecondActivity

```
 Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    String id=b.getString(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem: 
    If it runs onCreate again, it means it has been destroyed. It would be nice if you could post how your tablayout is created.

Secondly:
For sharing data between activities you shouldn't use SharedPreferences, you should pass data in an intent.
SharedPreferences is designed for storing persistent data in your app.

So it should look like the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MySettings.class);
intent.putExtra(MySettings.PARAM, "200");
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

And for retrieving it in your MySettings as follows:

```
 public class MySettings extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String PARAM = "myvar";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_inr);

        String param = getIntent().getStringExtras(PARAM);
}
```

Third one:

Your var is not being saved because every time you call edit(), it creates a new instance of an Editor, so no value is saved. So just need to change

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("myvar",200);
    sharedpreferences.edit().apply();
```

into

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("myvar",200).apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Luis, that solved my second problem. From within the second activity I used

```
sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("myvar",200).commit();
```

Instead of

```
    sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("myvar",200);
    sharedpreferences.edit().commit();
```

Again...thanks for everyones quick responses.

Comment: Glad it helped. I would use the apply() instead for making it asynchronous. About your question about if sharedpreferences is the way to go with, think about the following: if the next time you open your app you need those changes made in your settings to be shown, it is the way to go. In other case, its something temporal, so its not the best workaround. If you are in the sencond case, you should use intenta again. Search for startActivityForResult to see how to implement it. There are tons of examples out there.